# Table with Multirow --> How to get rid of the errors?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I have got a serious problem with a table. This is my code so far:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|cl|cl|cl|cl|cl|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}                             & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{M1}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{M2}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{M3}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{M4}        \\ \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{a1} & a2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,3} & 0,5 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,1} & 0,2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,3} & 0,8 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,4} & 0,7 \\  
\multirow{A1}                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0,1}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}         \\  
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-5}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3}         \\ \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{a1} & a2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,3} & 0,5 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,1} & 0,2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4}   & 2   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,1} & 0,2 \\  
\multirow{A2}                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0,1}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}         \\ 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-5}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-2}        \\ \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{a1} & a2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,3} & 0,5 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,1} & 0,2 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{4}   & 2   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0,1} & 0,2 \\ 
\multirow{A3}                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{b}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{2}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0,1}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}         \\   
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{c}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0}         & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-5}        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{-2}        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Unfortunately I got some errors, even when I add `\usepackage{multirow}` in the header. Can anyone help me solving this issue?

The table I want to have should look like this but I am not able to do it:

[image: table]

Thanks.

F

Comment: `\begin{table}[h]
\begin{table}[h]` will give errors even before your table starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are complicationg things. First `\multirow` has this syntax:

```
\multirow{rows}{width}{content}
```

Second, you have an extra `\begin{table}`. Having said this, your table can be simplified like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{|c}|}
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & M1          & M2            & M3           & M4            \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A1}  & a1 \quad a2 & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 0,3 \quad 0,8 & 0,4 \quad 0,7 \\
                     & b           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             \\
                     & c           & 1             & 0             & -5            & 3             \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A2}  & a1 \quad a2 & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 4 \quad 2     & 0,1 \quad 0,2 \\
                     & b           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             \\
                     & c           & 1             & 0             & -5            & -2            \\ \hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{A3} & a1 \quad a2 & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 4 \quad 2     & 0,1 \quad 0,2 \\
                     & b           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             \\
                     & c           & 1             & 0             & -5            & -2            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to use `$` for negative numbers like `$-5$` to get minus sign correct. With `booktabs`, you can have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1.2em}
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & M1          & M2            & M3            & M4            \\ \midrule
                     & a1 \quad a2 & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 0,3 \quad 0,8 & 0,4 \quad 0,7 \\
 A1                  & b           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             \\
                     & c           & 1             & 0             & $-5$          & 3             \\ [1.5ex] %\midrule
                     & a1 \quad a2 & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 4 \quad 2     & 0,1 \quad 0,2 \\
     A2              & b           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             \\
                     & c           & 1             & 0             & $-5$          & $-2$          \\ [1.5ex] %\midrule
                     & a1 \quad a2 & 0,3 \quad 0,5 & 0,1 \quad 0,2 & 4 \quad 2     & 0,1 \quad 0,2 \\
      A3             & b           & 3             & 2             & 0,1           & 1             \\
                     & c           & 1             & 0             & $-5$          & $-2$          \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico I found myself in a huge mess and getting out was slow :-). Now corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, that fast a very quick answer! Thanks. :)

Comment: @Ferit Glad it helped. Please remember to up vote (this needs 15 rep points minimum) and accept the more helpful answer. For details see [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Comment: @HarishKumar: I accepted. :) One more question which I forgot before. How can I color the table as follow? 

http://i.imgur.com/AY3XwgY.png

Comment: @Ferit Try with `colortbl`. This deserves to be a separate question.

Comment: In the `booktabs` case, I'd avoid `\multirow`, lining the left column entry with the first row of the group, or it appears as hanging from nowhere; adding also `\midrule` between groups seems better.

Comment: Note it's good practice to put the positive numbers in `$` as well, Knuth has an article somewhere where he comments that he made this error, it makes no difference in default setup but then he switched to concrete math (I think) where the math digits and text digits use a different font, and you want positive and negative numbers to use the same font....